# What is correct approach of deleting a row from table in Kotlin(Springboot) with JpaRepository from Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

So I'm learning Kotlin and learning how to make it look clean with Spring.

Lets say i have a repository for user Entity:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

Then i want to delete the user by it's id fristly i did something like that:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
fun deleteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") id: Long): ResponseEntity<Void> {
    return t.findById(id).map {
        t.delete(it)
        ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)
    }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
}
```

Where t was UserRepository and it was working just fine and looked clean.

But then I wanted to get retrieving object from database logic outside of the controller so I made a service.

How do I go about deleting an object through service I made something like this in the Service class:

```
fun deleteById(id: Long): Boolean = t.findById(id).map {
    t.delete(it)
    true
}.orElse(false)
```

Where t is the Repository, then in my Controller class I made adjustments like so:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
fun deleteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") id: Long): ResponseEntity<Void> = if (t.deleteById(id)) ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK) else ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
```

Where t is the service, but it looks very unclean. So how do i go about making Additional layer like the Service here and making the code more clean?

Comment: JpaRepository has deleteById, by the way. Or do you have some other logic that you’re just not showing in your service?

Comment: How do i do a not Found response then if there is no such ID? Anyways my question applies to findById aswell and GET mapping of the same controller. I Just wanna know how do i make the logic inside service and then still respond with correct responses like NotFound and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already very short and the possibility of size reduction is very thin, but I guess you can still do following

In your `service`

```
// use JpaRepository's (existsById) which return a boolean
fun deleteById(id: Long) = if(t.existsById(id)) {t.deleteById(id); true} else false
```

and in your `controller`

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
fun deleteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") id: Long) = if (t.deleteById(id)) ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK) else ResponseEntity<HttpStatus)(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

***Important:*** Please note that in general ***you should write code which is easily understandable and managable by others***, if someone had to waste 15 mins understanding a simple if statement just because you made it a one liner then that is not very good programming.

***As a great programmer once said***

> Every function should be made as small as possible, but not smaller

Comment: I just wanted to know if i can make it without returning false somehow more kotlin way like in the first example because:

    t.findById(id).map {
        t.delete(it)
        true
    }.orElse(false)

because last line seems off I could make it return Optional but it seems even less Kotlin since it returns Java object.